# Slice assignment in loop in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 5x3 matrix of zeros that I want to update with ones while in a while_loop. I want to use the looping variable to be the indices argument of the scatter_nd_update function. I have my code like this:

```
# Zeros matrix
num = tf.get_variable('num', shape=[5, 3], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), dtype=tf.float32)
# Looping variable
i = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
# Conditional
c = lambda i, num: tf.less(i, 2)
def body(i, num):
    # Update values
    updates = tf.ones([1, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
    num = tf.scatter_nd_update(num, [[i]], updates)
    return tf.add(i, 1), num
i, num = tf.while_loop(c, body, [i, num])
# Session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    num_out = sess.run(num)
    print(num_out.shape)
    print(num_out)
```

This throws an error that says: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'handle'` and points to the line `num = tf.scatter_nd_update(num, [[i]], updates)`

When I run this code without a loop by running `num = tf.scatter_nd_update(num, [[i]], updates)` twice with different i values then it works and I get a matrix with 2 rows of ones, but this error occurs when I try the same thing in a while_loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue revolves around the fact that [`tf.scatter_nd_update()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update) needs a ***variable*** to change, while [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) uses ***tensors*** as loop variables. Fundamentally, [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) runs the loop while setting up the graph, while [`tf.scatter_nd_update()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update) is an *operation* that would run when the network is running.

To say it another way, your created network will have three `num` tensors: one with the original zeros, then following that one another with the first row replaced, then following that one yet another with the first two rows replaced. To make that happen you can use this code (tested), more explanation below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
num = tf.zeros( shape = ( 5, 3 ), dtype = tf.float32 )
# Looping variable
i = tf.zeros( shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)
# Conditional
c = lambda i, num: tf.less(i, 2)
def body(i, num):
    # Update values
    updates = tf.ones([1, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
    num_shape = num.get_shape()
    num = tf.concat( [ num[ : i ], updates, num[ i + 1 : ] ], axis = 0 )
    num.set_shape( num_shape )
    return tf.add(i, tf.ones( shape=(), dtype = tf.int32 ) ), num
i, num = tf.while_loop( c, body, [ i, num ] )
# Session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    num_out = sess.run( [ num ] )
    print(num_out)
```

Output:

> [array([[1., 1., 1.],
>          [1., 1., 1.],
>          [0., 0., 0.],
>          [0., 0., 0.],
>          [0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)]

First of all, notice that I've changed `num` to a tensor from a variable. This will allow it to be used as a loop variable in [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop). Second, the scatter operation doesn't have a nice way to do on tensors, so I'm basically taking `num` apart (before-`i` and after-`i`, and insert `update` in between). We also have to set the shape for `num` otherwise the [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) will complain that the shape is uncertain (because of the [`tf.concat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat); there is a way around this with the use of the `shape_invariants` argument in [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) but this was easier for our case.)